# Add a checkbox to show / hide checkout fields in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

Let's skim over the scenerio:

Customer is on the checkout page, and there is a checkbox with text: "Is this a gift?"

If the checkbox selected, a field below will fade in to take notes.

Based on this thread and some other threads here is my code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'display_checkbox_and_new_checkout_field' );   
function display_checkbox_and_new_checkout_field( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing']['checkbox_trigger'] = array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'label'     => __('Checkbox label', 'woocommerce'),
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true
    );  

    $fields['billing']['new_billing_field'] = array(
        'label'     => __('New Billing Field Label', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('New Billing Field Placeholder', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true
    );

    return $fields;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'conditionally_hide_show_new_field', 6 );
function conditionally_hide_show_new_field() {
      ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery('input#checkbox_trigger').change(function(){

                if (this.checked) {
                    jQuery('#new_billing_field_field').fadeOut();
                    jQuery('#new_billing_field_field input').val('');           
                } else {
                    jQuery('#new_billing_field_field').fadeIn();
                }

            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Problem is the field which should fade in when box is checked comes visible already.

How can I alter the script to make in invisible on load?

Comment: You could add something like this to your script tag to hide the element on page load:

    `$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#new_billing_field").hide();
    });`

Comment: @tshimkus where should I add it? The script should load specificly on checkout page but which file should I go with?

Comment: It could go anywhere, but the existing script tag in your code would work. It will hide the form when the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'conditionally_show_hide_checkout_field' );
function conditionally_show_hide_checkout_field() {
    ?>
    <style>
    p#new_billing_field_field.on { display:none !important; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        var a = 'input#checkbox_trigger',   b = '#new_billing_field_field'

        $(a).change(function(){
            if ( $(this).prop('checked') === true && $(b).hasClass('on') ) {
                $(b).show(function(){
                    $(b).css({'display':'none'}).removeClass('on').show();
                });
            }
            else if ( $(this).prop('checked') !== true && ! $(b).hasClass('on') ) {
                $(b).fadeOut(function(){
                    $(b).addClass('on')
                });
                $(b+' input').val('');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'add_custom_checkout_fields' );
function add_custom_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing']['checkbox_trigger'] = array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'label'     => __('Checkbox label', 'woocommerce'),
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true
    );

    $fields['billing']['new_billing_field'] = array(
        'label'     => __('New Billing Field Label', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('New Billing Field Placeholder', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide on'),
        'clear'     => true
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks so much, technically it works like a charm. There is just one issue with the styling. If you check out the [link](https://prnt.sc/mnazpk) you see the checkbox and label are next to each other. There I found some snippets on several pages but didn't work out. Any idea?

Comment: Since you marked my latest question as too broad, I did [revise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54972422/11080780) it. I don’t know if my edits pops up so I decided bother you from here. I think using here needs a learning curve. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MehmetAliGörür The community has marked your question as too broad, because you are expected to provide some code in your answer. Remember that stackOverFlow is not a free coding service. People only will help you on your related code that shows your coding effort in solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reminder. I will keep that in mind next time. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. What if you want to show/hide multiple fields? I made VAR B an array but it doesnt work so far...

Comment: @Kees For multiple fields, you can have a unique string with all individual field selectors coma separated like: `b = '#new_billing_field_field1,#new_billing_field_field2';`… So no need to complicate things with an array. Also if you like/want and if this answer is useful, don't forget to upvote it.