# Show additional information depending on shipping selected

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I would like to show additional information/order notes when a specific shipping method was selected.

I have multiple shipping options and when selecting a specific one I need the user to provide a different address in the note, please see the images below:

These are the available shipping options:

[image]

---

I want to show this (and it has to be a required field)

[image]

---

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66162649/5550161) answer where a checkbox is used to show/hide the notes of an order on the checkout page:

[image]

By doing the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_checkout_order_notes' );
function custom_checkout_order_notes( $fields ) {
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['class'][] = 'off';
    return $fields;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'checkout_checkbox_show_hide_order_notes' );
function checkout_checkbox_show_hide_order_notes( $fields ) {
    $target_id = 'order_comments';
    ?>
    <style> p#<?php echo $target_id; ?>_field.off { display:none;}</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        var a = 'input#checkbox_trigger',       b = '#<?php echo $target_id; ?>_field';

        $(b).hide('fast');

        $(a).change(function(){
            if( $(b).hasClass('off') ) {
                $(b).removeClass('off');
            }

            if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) {
               $(b).show('fast');
            } else {
                $(b).hide('fast', function(){
                    $(b+' input').val('');
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php

    woocommerce_form_field( 'checkbox_trigger', array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'label'     => __('Add a note to your order?', 'woocommerce'),
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true,
    ), false );
}
```

But this is not what I want as described above.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I have added comments to help future readers.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_billing_fields','woocommerce_check_if_shipping_changed' );
function woocommerce_check_if_shipping_changed() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

    // Get the selected shipping method
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0]; 

    // Check if it is one of the two I want to show "Aditional Information" for (using their ID's)
    // I used developer tools to get their ID's
    if ($chosen_shipping == 'wbs:6:5977f58e_postnet_to_postnet' || $chosen_shipping == 'wbs:6:014e3dff_pudo_locker') { 
        if ($chosen_shipping == 'wbs:6:014e3dff_pudo_locker'){
            // Change additional notes label to : Pudo Locker Address:
            add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'make_order_label_pudo', 9999, 1);
        }
        if ($chosen_shipping == 'wbs:6:5977f58e_postnet_to_postnet'){
            // Change additional notes label to : PostNet Address:
            add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'make_order_label_postnet', 9999, 1);
        }
        // Show order notes
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_enable_order_notes_field', '__return_true', 9999 );
        // Make order notes required
        add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'make_order_notes_required_field', 9999, 1);

    }else{
        // Hide order notes
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_enable_order_notes_field', '__return_false', 9999 );
        // Make order notes not a requirement
        add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'make_order_notes_not_required_field', 9999, 1);
    }
    
}

function make_order_label_pudo( $fields ) {
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'Pudo Locker Address:';
    return $fields;
}

function make_order_label_postnet( $fields ) {
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'PostNet Address:';
    return $fields;
}

function make_order_notes_required_field( $fields ) {
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['required'] = true;
    return $fields;
}

function make_order_notes_not_required_field( $fields ) {
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['required'] = false;
    return $fields;
}

// The page needs to be refreshed of the changes to apply
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_shipping_refresh' );
function checkout_shipping_refresh() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?><script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        let isRefreshPage = false;
        $('form.checkout').on('change','input[name^="shipping_method"]',function() {
            const val = $( this ).val();
            isRefreshPage = true;
        });
    
        $('body').on('updated_checkout', function(){
            if (isRefreshPage) {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```